# Implementing firebase Crashlytics in Flutter - Could not find method classpath() for arguments

Tags: flutter

Please help... :(

I get this error when trying to implement Firebase Crashlytics in Flutter:

- Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta02]

**This is the full error message:**

```
Launching lib/main_ADHD.dart on HTC 10 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\lars\OneDrive - Aalborg Universitet\Programmering\Flutter projekter\meditationsguitarapps\android\app\build.gradle' line: 48

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta02] on DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=dk.ADHD, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         8,7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is my **Android/app/build.gradle**:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "dk.ADHD"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta02'

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            /* Add the firebaseCrashlytics extension (by default,
            * it's disabled to improve build speeds) and set
            * nativeSymbolUploadEnabled to true. */
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

This is my **Android/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'   // new
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'



    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my **pubspec.yaml**:

```
name: meditationsguitar
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

version: 1.0.0+34

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  in_app_purchase: 0.2.2+4
  audioplayers: ^0.12.1
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  share: 0.6.3+5
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.10
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+6
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.3




  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  basic_utils: ^1.8.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"
  url_launcher: ^5.1.3
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0



flutter_icons:
#  android: "launcher_icon"
  android: true
  ios: true
  #image_path: "assets/images/meditationForBoern/icon/icon.jpg"
  #image_path: "assets/images/mindfulEating/icon/icon.png"
  image_path: "assets/images/ADHD/icon/icon.jpg"



# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   # - assets/images/meditationForBoern/
   # - assets/audio/meditationForBoern/
   # - assets/images/mindfulEating/
   # - assets/audio/mindfulEating/
    - assets/images/ADHD/
    - assets/audio/ADHD/



  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
fonts:
  - family: Roboto
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf
        weight: 900

  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've accidentally added the Firebase build scripts for an android app. However, since this is Flutter you don't need them. Anything you need to add will be found on the official [pub.dev documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics) for firebase_crashlytics. Follow the steps listed below along with what's on pub.dev and your issue should be resolved.

Remove the line in your **android/build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
```

Remove the lines in your **android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1'
```

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
    nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
}
```

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta02'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta02'
```

if you don't need this line remove it from android/app/build.gradle
or otherwise remove it from there and add it to android/build.gradle

class paths are not added in android/app/build.gradle also not inside defaultConfig. It is added inside dependencies.